# Underscore before theme name

Tags: drupal

I was browsing the template.php file for the rootcandy theme and noticed some of the function names start with an underscore i.e.

```
function _rootcandy_admin_links()

function rootcandy_body_class()
```

Anyone know why this is? I thought the functions had to start with the name of the theme.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conventionally, underscores at the beginning of identifiers mean "This is private/internal stuff. You probably don't want to mess with it from other modules."

Comment: Thanks Sam. I didn't consider that you could just write your own functions in the template.php so it makes sense to underscore them with you theme name.

Answer (score -1):

What SamB says, and also: functions in template.php only have to start with the theme name if they are meant to override an existing theme function. For example, when overriding `theme_foo($variables)`, you use `mytheme_foo($variables)` in the template.php of the 'mytheme' theme. It's perfectly okay to add your own functions, like `calculate_some_value()` or `_calculate_some_value()`, if that helps you code your theme.

Comment: Generally due the lack of namespace in PHP, you don't create functions that doesn't contain the module or theme name to avoid naming colission. But this is a best practice not a requirement.

Comment: -1 - **It is not 'perfectly ok'** to name your own functions as you wish! While it is correct that only overrides are *technically required* to start with the theme name, other functions should do this as well to *prevent naming clashes with other modules/themes* (the prefix convention is a kind of 'poor mans' solution to the lack of namespaces in PHP)

Comment: Please, if you quote, quote correctly. I'm not saying that it's okay to name as you wish. All I meant to say, is that it's okay to add your own functions besides theme override functions. I apologize if I didn't make myself clear enough. Proper namespacing is always good practice.

Comment: @marcvanged: Sorry for the imprecise quoting! I think I understood you alright - I just wanted to emphasize the point that the naming convention should be followed for non-override functions as well, even if not required.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. Very helpful:)

Comment: @Henrik: ok, I understand, no hurt feelings.